# Signature problems in Php resulting in API authentication failing

Tags: php, api, hmacsha1

I am trying to get the list of IP addresses using Verizon Cloud REST API's.

Eventhough all the values are correct,I am unable to authenticate due to some reasons which I am not able to find

Here is a link to the documentation - http://cloud.verizon.com/documentation/CloudAPIAuthentication.htm

Whether I am doing something wrong here..because it always returns me forbidden access 403 error access whereas it should return a 401 for me.

```
<?php

 ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
{
//Access Key and Secret Key
$accesskey="XXXXX";
$secretkey="XXXXXXXX";

//Generating a Authorization Header data
$method = 'GET';
$host = 'https://api.cloud.verizon.com/';
$HTTPVerb = "GET";
$ContentType = "";
$CanonicalizedAmzHeaders = "";
$time=time();
$CanonicalizedResource = "api/compute/ip-address";

$string_to_sign = $HTTPVerb . "\n" .$ContentType."\n".$time ."\n".$CanonicalizedAmzHeaders."\n".$CanonicalizedResource;
$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $string_to_sign, $secretkey, TRUE));
$request = 'accesskey='.$accesskey.'<BR>signaturetype=HmacSHA256<BR>signature='.$signature;
$authorization='CloudApi '.$request;

//Generating header data for x-tmrk-date and x-tmrk-noonce
date_default_timezone_set("GMT");
$date=date("D d F Y H:i:s", time())." GMT";
$noonce=time();

//auth

// Generating requests
include('./httpful.phar');
$uri='https://sjca1.cloud.verizon.com/api/';

//Sending Headers  
$response = \Httpful\Request::options($uri)
    ->addHeaders(array(
        'Accept'=>'application/vnd.terremark.ecloud.root.v1+json',  
        'x-tmrk-authorization' => $authorization,           
        'x-tmrk-date' => $date,  
        'x-tmrk-nonce' => $noonce,           
        'Authorization' => $authorization,
        'Date' => $date,
    ))
    ->send();
echo "<pre>";
echo $response;
```

}
?>

Answer (score 0):

From your example, it does not look like you Canonicalize the Headers. Follow the steps here.: http://cloud.verizon.com/documentation/CloudAPISignatureGeneration.htm#o5461

Canonicalized headers are required only when you use x-tmrk-date. Otherwise, use a blank line.
1.Retrieve all header fields for the resource that begin with "x-tmrk-" excluding the x-tmrk-authorization header field, if present. 
2.Convert each HTTPS header field name to lowercase.
3.Sort the header fields lexicographically by header field name, in ascending order. Note that each header may appear only once in the string. 
4.Unfold the string by replacing any breaking whitespace with a single space. 
5.Trim any whitespace around the colon in the header field. 
6.Append a newline character to each canonicalized header field in the resulting list. 
7.Concatenate all headers in this list into a single string as the CanonicalizedHeaders string.

Constructing the CanonicalizedResource string

This signature string is the resource string in lowercase. For example:
/api/compute/vm

Follow the string with parameters, as described in the following procedure.
1.Use the decoded URL for the resource, converted to all lowercase, as the source for the CanonicalizedResource.
2.Append the resource's URI path, that portion of the call after the URI and before any query parameters (query parameters of a URI is the part of the URI after the question mark, "?"), followed by a newline ('\n') character.
3.Retrieve all query parameters on the resource URL.
Tip: Separate query parameters using the ampersand character, "&". For example, [?[offset=x][&limit=y]]

4.Convert all parameter names to lowercase.
5.Sort the query parameters lexicographically by parameter name, in ascending order.
6.Append each query parameter name and value to the string, in order, in the following format, making sure to include the colon (:) between the name and the value, followed by a newline character after each name-value pair: 
parameter-name:parameter-value\